# hiding an html section with angularjs on right button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

with angularjs or jquery, how can i hide the html section "sec1" whenever the user right clicks with the mouse inside the canvas area? and show it back again when the user clicks with the left mouse button and viceversa?
i know i can use $event.which but im alittle confused thanks

```html
<body
         ng-app="appMyExample" 
         ng-controller="MainCtrl" background="images.jpe">
        
    <h2>title</h2>
    
        <canvas 
            ng-mousedown="defineSquare($event)"
            oncontextmenu="return false"
            id="GLCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:2px solid #e3d3d3;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas.
        </canvas>
    <br>
    <b>Total on screen:</b><input type="text" value="0" id="total">
    <b>Erase<input type="radio" value="Erase"></b><input type="text" value="0" id="erase">
    <br>
    <section id="sec1">
        <css-timer id="idMainControllerTimer"
               interval="40"
               timeron="true"
               callback="mainTimerHandler"></css-timer>
    </section>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="mSelection" name="shape" value="Square" ng-change="swap(1)" checked="checked">Square
            <input type="radio" ng-model="mSelection" name="shape" value="Circle" ng-change="swap(2)">Circle
        </div> 
        
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-hide` on the section that you want to hide:

```
<section id="sec1" ng-hide="hideSec1">
    <css-timer id="idMainControllerTimer"
           interval="40"
           timeron="true"
           callback="mainTimerHandler"></css-timer>
</section>
```

Use the `$event.button` property in the mousedown  handler:

```
$scope.defineSquare =  function (event) {
    if (event.button == 2) {
        $scope.hideSec1 = true;
    } else {
        $scope.hideSec1 = false;
    };
};
```

Avoid the `ng-if` directive because it destroys/creates the DOM element (unless you really want to destroy the css-timer).

Also be aware that `ng-click` only fires on clicks of the main mouse button. It does not detect clicks on the other mouse buttons. Instead use `ng-mousedown` or `ng-mouseup`.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9s78p5c/)

Comment: in the if (event.button == 2) {
        $scope.hideSec1 = "true";
    } , hides the section.  And when the user clicks the left mouse button again the section should appear again. i tried everything but it's not working for me

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to define an ng-click on the "sec1" section, and act if there was a right-click.

e.g. - on the section add:

```
ng-click="handleClick($event)"
```

And on your controller check if $event.which === 3 and act accordingly (for example, you can set some var $scope.hidden = true and use "ng-if" on that var to remove the "sec1" from the DOM).

Hope that helps.